# How to filter a string to only include characters that are allowed?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to filter a string to only contain characters that I allow. For example let's say I allow letters [A-Z] (case insensitive) and underscores ('_').

So let's say I have the string:
`"I am a happy_bear and I sk@8 because it's gr8"`

I would want it to be filtered to:
`"I am a happy_bear and I sk because its gr"`

What I have tried so far:

```java
//Define a method to check allowed charachters
 private boolean checkAllowed(Character ch) {
        return Character.isLetter(ch) || ch == '_';
    }
```

```java
// loop through string
for (int i = 0; i < someString.length(); i++) {
            if (this.checkAllowed(someString.charAt(i)) {
                // append to a list
            }
        }
```

How can I filter a string to only include characters that I allow? Is that achievable with a stream-like filtering? Can this be done easier without regex? (I am looking for a better way to do this)

Comment: What's the problem now? you've just done what you wanted, didn't you? you can also add "empty space" to the `checkAllowed` function (or just check it in the for loop) and you will be done. In Scala, you could also use `filter` method on list (of characters), but I don't know the functionality of filter in Java.

Comment: You can use simple regex. `String result = str.replaceAll("[^_A-Za-z ]", "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that achievable with a stream-like filtering?

yes it is:

```
String s = "I am a happy_bear and I sk@8 because it's gr8";

String d = s.codePoints()
    .filter(c -> Character.isLetter(c) || c == '_' || c == ' ')
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();

System.out.println(d);

...

I am a happy_bear and I sk because its gr
```

[`codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints()) returns

> an IntStream of Unicode code points from this sequence

the stream is then filtered and [collected](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

a regex solution may be more concise and simple though, look at [`replaceAll() method`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).

your loop and "check method" is also fine, just use a `StringBuilder` to create a new string containing only the characters that "pass" the check.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party library, the following will work with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
@Test
public void stringFilter()
{
    String string = Strings.asChars("I am a happy_bear and I sk@8 because it's gr8")
            .select(this::checkAllowed)
            .toString();
    Assert.assertEquals("I am a happy_bear and I sk because its gr", string);
}

private boolean checkAllowed(Character ch)
{
    return Character.isLetter(ch) || ch == '_' || Character.isSpaceChar(ch);
}
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.